# How to remove number from toc title with pandoc+beamer

Tags: latex, pandoc, tableofcontents, beamer

I am using pandoc to generate a beamer slideshow.  I activated the generation of a TOC and specified a TOC headline.  But there is an extra number added to this title as if the TOC would span several slides, but it does not.

My source file

```
---
toc: true
toc-title: the overview
...

# my section
```

and I compile with `pandoc -t beamer -o x.pdf < x.md`.  The title of the TOC has this extra roman I which beamer normally adds if a slide is split into two (or more).

[image]

How can I get rid of this number?

###### Edit

In the end I put it in the yaml preamble of the pandoc file as raw latex code:

````yaml
header-includes: |
    ```{=latex}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
    % more stuff
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the continuation count for frames that consist only of a single one by using this command:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the response from @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I had to delimit the command with backticks and indicate as latex code:

```
`\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]`{=latex}
```

Comment: I had in the end done the same in the preamble, see the update of the question.